# Google Feed API to parse Google MyMaps GeoRSS?

Tags: google-api, georss

what's the best way to parse the geoRss coming from Goggle MyMaps?

I tried jFeed but i have cross-domain issues, i tried the Google's Feed Api but it doesnt give you the lat/lon but the title, author etc...

there is any way to choose the elements you want back in the Feed API?
or anyone knows a better way to parse a georss??

thanks!!